# store pointers to different types of classes in an std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism, unordered-map

I have devices I need to do operations on.  I have one base class `BASE` and a child class `TYPE1`.
Each device is an instance of `TYPE1`. These get instantiated by another class depending on what is present in an  xml configuration file.

```
class BASE {
public:
    BASE();
    virtual ~BASE();
};

class TYPE1 : public BASE {
public:
    TYPE1();
};
```

Now I store pointers to these instances in an `std::unordered_map` defined as:

```
std::unordered_map <std::string, TYPE1 *> myDevices;
```

with `std::string` being an identification key that is also used in configuration files.

The `std::unordered_map` gives me quick direct access to an object if I need it and the convenience to do the same operation on all the devices if I iterate through it using

```
for ( auto& elem : myDevices ) {
    //do stuff
}
```

The order of the devices is unimportant, hence the `std::unordered_map`.
I use that extensively throughout the code.

Now I have the need for a `TYPE2` that is also a child of `BASE` but nevertheless a different type.

`TYPE1` and `TYPE2` both have the same methods implemented - they function differently - but yield the same results

**My question :**

How do I modify

```
std::unordered_map <std::string, TYPE1 *> myDevices;
```

so it accepts all types of classes like

```
std::unordered_map <std::string, acceptAnyTypeOfClass *> myDevices;
```

I'm blocked with this and while I think I could get around it it would get ugly very quickly and I would really like to do it in a clean way. Is what I'm asking possible and if so how please?

Comment: `std::unordered_map <std::string, BASE *>`?

Comment: Use a `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<BASE>>`.

Comment: @Arch is on the right track.

Comment: I really don't get why this gets downvoted - is this such a stupid question then? probably... I'll look at std::unique_ptr<BASE> thank you.

Comment: @ZoOl007 _"is this such a stupid question then? "_ So Stack Overflow is about concrete problems you face with your approach, not about _if it's possible_. Provide a [MCVE], and clearly explain where you're stuck.

Comment: Don't worry about it.  This site has been getting progressively worse, with perfectly reasonable questions downvoted for spurious reasons.

Comment: @ZoOl007 _`acceptAnyTypeOfClass`_ is available with c++17 standard's [`std::any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) otherwise you can fallback to [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/any.html).

Comment: There's a world of difference between "accept any type of class" and "accept any BASE-derived class". Also note that ALL_CAPS names should be reserved for macros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first option that comes to mind would be to use a pointer to the base class, because `TYPE1` and `TYPE2` objects are all `BASE` objects:

```
std::unordered_map <std::string, BASE*> myDevices;
```

The question is then ho wto make the difference between `TYPE1*` pointers and `TYPE2*` pointers ?

As `TYPE1` and `TYPE2` both have the same methods implemented, the best approach would probably be to use polymorphism, using virtual functions:

```
class BASE {
public:
    BASE();
    virtual void doSomething()=0;  
    virtual ~BASE();
};

class TYPE1 : public BASE {
public:
    TYPE1();
    void doSometing() override { /* the code for TYPE 1 devices*/ }
};

class TYPE2 : public BASE {
public:
    TYPE2();
    void doSometing() override { /* the code for TYPE 2 devices*/ }
};
```

You can then invoke the functions without worrying about the true type of the base object:

```
std::unordered_map <std::string, BASE*> myDevices;
...
for (auto& elem : myDevices ) {
    elem->doSomething();  
}
```

*P.S:* If you create the device objects dynamically, you could consider using unique or shared pointers in the map, to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: ok, I'll give it a go later next week. I'll take some restructuring. In the mean time : Thank you for taking the time to give me a clear answer. I'll accept your answer after I've gotten it to work. I do create objects dynamically yes but I ran it through valgrind and it comes out clean. Thanks for the tip. That'll be next on my need to learn list then.

Comment: @ZoOl007: `std::unique_ptr` does not only avoid memory leaks but all kinds of nasty errors that come with manual memory management, including a lot of undefined behaviour (e.g. deleting twice, derefencing a `nullptr` and so on).

Comment: @Christophe I managed to adapt it according to what you told me. I cannot yet test type2 end to end but from the looks of it - it functions fine. Thank you very much for your time.